# I'm getting an exception when running the built-in authorization middleware

Tags: laravel, authentication, middleware

In Laravel 5.8 when adding authorization to my project using `php artisan make:auth`, I get an exception whenever the guest Is redirected to the login page.

> trying to get property 'headers' of non-object in
>   /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php

The line of code it refers to is $response->headers in:

```
    protected function addCookieToResponse($request, $response)
    {
        $config = config('session');

        $response->headers->setCookie(
            new Cookie(
                'XSRF-TOKEN', $request->session()->token(), $this->availableAt(60 * $config['lifetime']),
                $config['path'], $config['domain'], $config['secure'], false, false, $config['same_site'] ?? null
            )
        );

        return $response;
    }
```

I see lots of posts referring to the same exception in middleware, where the soulution often seems to have to do with making sure the user always is redirected in the controller.

What I don't understant is why this does not work out of the box.
Seems like the response-object is somewhat broken before entering the csrf-middleware.

For testing I installed a fresh version of Laravel with the same version number and ran make:auth. Then I compared everything I could think of referring to authorization between the two, and cant find any differences.

Does anyone have any clue what could be causing this?

Comment: did you create your own middleware or alter one of the default ones? is it returning a response object? if not the previous middleware wont have a response to work on  ... `make:auth` is authentication not authorization

Comment: I have created one route-middleware which is applied to one single sub route. But this mw is not called when i use my HomeController. And it does ```return $next($request);```

And my mistake. I ment authentication, not authorization

Comment: some thing is passing the wrong thing back through the middleware stack ... the first place to look is anything you added or altered or anything you are assigning to routes ... would be helpful to see that middleware as well to rule it out

Comment: I agree. something is passed incorrecly in the stack, but removing the custom middleware did nothing for the problem. 

Also difficult to look at things recently added as I've been building this project for a while and just now added the authentication.